# How to Listen for JCombobox Selection Event

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jcombobox, jpopup

When I select the `JCombobox` I want to handle an event when its selected and the dropdown is shown as well as handle the event when the drop down disappears and the `JCombobox` is de-selected.

Note, i'm not looking to listen for an item selection change but for when the user selects the `JCombobox` and the UI pops out the Dropdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [addPopupMenuListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addPopupMenuListener%28javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener%29) which uses the following interface:

```
public interface PopupMenuListener extends EventListener {

    /**
     *  This method is called before the popup menu becomes visible 
     */
    void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e);

    /**
     * This method is called before the popup menu becomes invisible
     * Note that a JPopupMenu can become invisible any time 
     */
    void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e);

    /**
     * This method is called when the popup menu is canceled
     */
    void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e);
}
```